# Get html from element from iFrame every 10 seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, element, replay

So i've been looking around for a while for a possible solution to make a javascript, jquery which searches in the iFrame for a certain class or id element. Then takes out the html inside of it. (example. `<a id="link">Here's a link</a>` ). then makes it a string out of it and also replay this function every 5 second or so. Is there anyone who know a good solution to this or a tutorial?

I've tried the function `var inf = $('#iframeid').contents().find('#theid').html();`but it didn't gave any success.

Comment: is theiframe source at the same domain? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/364952/jquery-javascript-accessing-contents-of-an-iframe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
function GetFrameData() {
    var $MyFrame = $("#iframeid");

    // You need to wait for the iFrame content to load first
    // So, that the click events work properly
    $MyFrame.load(function () {
        var frameBody = $MyFrame.contents().find('body');
        var inf = frameBody.find('#theid').html();
    });
}

// Call the function every 5 seconds
setInterval(GetFrameData, 5000);
```